# Unable to Mock the Database call handled by Spring JPA framework while writing test Case for Controller Class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, mockito, spring-data-rest

Spring MVC converts the id from path to corresponding object by making call to JpaRepository's findById method. For example see getVersionTree() method.

```
public class Controller {
    @NonNull
    private final MyService service;

    @NonNull
    private final MyAssembler assembler;

    @GetMapping(path = VERSION_TREE_MAPPING, produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<?> getVersionTree(@PathVariable("id") MappingDocument mappingDocument, Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<VersionNode> pagedResourcesAssembler) {
        Page<VersionNode> versionNodes = service.getVersionTreeFor(mappingDocument, pageable);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(pagedResources, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

While testing, SpringMVC throws " Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.rbc.dna.dtl.mappingdocument.MappingDocument'". I am mocking jpaRepository.findById() method. Test Code is as follows:

```
   @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Mock
    MyController controller;

    @MockBean
    private MyServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
            MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()).build();
            MappingDocument mappingDocumentl=MappingDocument.builder().id(17L).build();
            Mockito.when(repository.findById(17L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(mappingDocumentl));
            Mockito.when(serviceImpl.getVersionTreeFor(mappingDocument,pageable)).thenReturn(pagedResponse);

            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/abc/17/def").param("page","0").param("size","20").contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                    .with(authentication(getOauthTestAuthentication()))
                    .sessionAttr("scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext", getOauth2ClientContext()))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rest Controller take `@PathVariable("id") MappingDocument mappingDocument` as variable in your path, but in `mockMvc.perform` you are passing a simple String/Number or something that doesn't bind with MappingDocument.

Try to replace

`public HttpEntity<?> getVersionTree(@PathVariable("id") MappingDocument mappingDocument...`

with

`public HttpEntity<?> getVersionTree(@PathVariable("id") Long idMappingDocument, ...`

---

If you want to keep your object in `@PathVariable` you need to change

```
@GetMapping(path = VERSION_TREE_MAPPING)
```

To parse an object as `PathVariable` you need to have path that represent property of your object.

For example if you have

```
class Person {

    String name;

    String address;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and you need to define a controller as follow:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/person/{name}/{address}", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<?> getVersionTree(Person person) {
```

Where `{name}` and `{address}` must bind `Person` properties

Comment: the mockMvc.perfrom statement is equivalent as mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/abc/{id}/def", 17). This ID will get mapped to MappingDocument Object internally handled by JPA framework and spring mvc .@GetMapping can't be changed as String.

Comment: Yes this is clear, what i'm asking is `@GetMapping(path = VERSION_TREE_MAPPING` and in particular `VERSION_TREE_MAPPING` because i have to understand how it's possibile to bind what you are passing in `MockMvcRequestBuilders` in a `MappingDocument` defined as `@PathVariable`

Comment: value of VERSION_TREE_MAPPING is '/abc/{id}/def". The URL. Kindly let me know if understand the question correctly and more details are required

Comment: In your test, you are passing a `@PathVariable` that is a `Long` in your `{id}`. Instead you have defined a `@PathVariable("id") MappingDocument mappingDocument` in your controller. Have you tried to replace `@PathVariable("id") MappingDocument mappingDocument` with `@PathVariable("id") Long id` ?

Comment: yes, if we  change it to Long id in controller, it will work but we can't change it to Long. It should be its respective object. This is how it is designed,